# What is the point in using Monte Carlo methods to measure statistical estimators?

Tags: variance, monte-carlo, random-generation, estimators

Let's say I have a dataset that is 100 elements long,

$X = \{x_0...x_{100}\}$

and I do 1,000 Monte Carlo realizations of the data, $X_j, 0\leq j \leq1000$, sampling 10 points each time.

If I then compute the variance (or any other estimator) on those ten points, and do that for every realization, I can then use that to tell me about the variance of the whole dataset.

$Var(X) \approx \dfrac{\sum_{j=0}^{1000}Var(X_j)}{1000}$

So, why would I do this? If I take those 1,000 variances, and average them, shouldn't it just converge to the variance of the whole set, if I were to measure it once? Is the only reason to do it this way to be able to measure the error on the computed variance?

Comment: Do you want an answer to the general question or just to variances. in the special way you use Monte Carlo in your question?

Comment: @MichaelChernick In general. In my specific case, I'm using the technique to find a biweight dispersion from an unknown distribution. I just used the variance as a simpler example. But even in my more specific case, I don't see why taking a bunch of measurements from a small sample is so beneficial, if I would expect it to converge to one measurement from a large sample. Unless the only goal is to attain the uncertainty in your found value of the estimator.

Comment: I  was trying to see if the bootstrap could apply.  Bootstrap estimates of populations parameters are usually approximated using Monte Carlo. Also  no method is very accurate in very small samples there are cases where it can be surprisingly good in small samples. Efron showed in an article in 1983 that in classification problems that some bootstrap methods did better than cross-validation (Lachenbruch's leave one out method).  Especially notable was the 632 bootstrap.  In a series of papers that I coauthored we widened the applications.  Later Efron and others also pursued this.